# Unable run Flyway migrations in Spring Boot Gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, docker, hibernate, gradle, flyway

I am currently trying to build a Spring Boot application, using Gradle. As for my tools, I decided to use Docker for my PostgreSQL database (I don't want to dockerize my whole app just yet) and Flyway for the migrations. I am also using Windows (yep, not the best option, I know...)
I looked up some configuration options and that's what I ended up with:

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2'
    id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '9.21.0'
}

group = 'com.ywa'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:9.21.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
//  testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/dml-local-db'
}
```

application.properties

```
#--Remote host main--
#spring.datasource.url= ---
#spring.datasource.username= ---
#spring.datasource.password= ---

#--Local host for devs--
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/dml-local-db
spring.datasource.username= ---
spring.datasource.password= ---

spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.user= ---
spring.flyway.password= ---

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Application

```
package com.ywa.dml;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DmlApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DmlApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

I start up my docker container using `docker compose up`, and `gradle flywayMigrate -i` to run the migrations. Problem is - everything works fine until I ran the flywayMigrate command, that's where I get the following errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'dml'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.2.
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.1.2
      > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies
 declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.1.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin-maven-optional:3.1.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared extern
ally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.2')
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? How can I fix that?
Also, is there any other way to set this whole system up? I'd like to have something like a script or anything that would automatically, after running one simple command, start both the Docker and Flyway migrations after it.

Here you have my current project's structure, in case it might help:
[image: Project's current structure]

Comment: I think, you should change your gradle jvm to Java 17

Comment: A-a-and that's the problem... I already did, it was set to JVM since the start of the project...
https://imgur.com/a/Bv8M101

Comment: Have you tried setting `targetCompatibility = '17'` too? As the gradle build file only specifies `sourceCompatibility`. And what version of gradle are you using? Is it 8.0.2?

Comment: A big "yes" to both things and still nothing seems to work :(
The thing is that setting targetCompatibility would do nothing, I assume, as it's being set to the project and takes matter in it's hands once the app is running, but as I'm trying to use the terminal to activate my migration - it doesn't appear to be the case to solve it.
Also, it seems strange to me that even though I can't run my migrations by terminal, once I start the project, Flyway reads the migrations, validates them, tells me they're OK, but still ignores them and doesn't change anything within the database.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gHei3uq